# .Net Core Web API Request Redirecting

Tags: redirect, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have controllers AController and BController and both of them has a method that name is upload.

This is the sample code;

```
public class AController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file) {
        
    }
}

public class BController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file) {
        
    }
}
```

The user will call the upload method of AController and I want to redirect this request to upload method of BController after check and confirm something.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution is

```
public class AController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file) {
        return new RedirectResult("/b/Upload", true, true);
    }
}
```

but I couldn't figure how to retain the parameters

Comment: No, it is redirectiong only for get methods and doesn't sent the parameters